# Strip leading characters from a directory path in a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

So i am attempting to teach myself C#, I have a program that I originally wrote in batch and am attempting to recreate in C# using WPF. I have a button that allows a user to set a directory, that directory selected is then displayed in a text box above a listbox which adds every subfolder, only first level, to the listbox. Now all this works fine but it writes out the entire directory path in the listbox. I have been trying to figure out how to strip the leading directory path off the list box entries for over an hour to no avail. Here is what I have so far:

```
    private void btn_SetDirectory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a folder browser dialog and set the selected path to "steamPath"
        var steamPath = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = steamPath.ShowDialog();

        //Update the text box to reflect the selected folder path
        txt_SteamDirectory.Text = steamPath.SelectedPath;

        //Clear and update the list box after choosing a folder
        lb_FromFolder.Items.Clear();

        string folderName = steamPath.SelectedPath;
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
            {
                lb_FromFolder.Items.Add(f);
            }
    }
```

Now I tried changing the last line to this, and it did not work it just crashed the program:

```
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
    {
        lb_FromFolder.Items.Add(f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("'\'")));
    }
```

I am fairly certain that the LastIndexOf route is probably the right one but I am at a dead end. I apologize if this is a dumb question but this is my first attempt at using C#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need only name of the folder??

Comment: Correct just the name of the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can solve your issue

```
 string folderName = steamPath.SelectedPath;
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
    {
       // string[] strArr = f.Split('\\');
        lb_FromFolder.Items.Add(f.Split('\\')[f.Split('\\').Length-1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
string folderName = steamPath.SelectedPath;
foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
{
  lb_FromFolder.Items.Add(f.Remove(0,folderName.Length));
}
```